# What are hydrodynamic modes?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

What are hydrodynamic and non-hydrodynamic modes in a fluid? Apparently, they are connected with the analytic structure of the correlation function of conserved quantities. I need a pedagogic explanation or an introductory reference.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Physics.StackEx*  ,  have you tried to search for references(if so, can you show us what did/didn't work?)  and, what do you specifically mean by *pedagogic explanation or an introductory reference* ?  Since there is different "levels" of just how "introductory" material might be presented :) (broadly speaking)